# Mercurial on server can't find hgrc

Tags: mercurial

I've just installed mercurial onto my server for team central repo, i've cloned the repo onto my local machine all worked fine, i've made changes and committed them to my local repo, but when i push to central command i get "ssl required" error. After researching it seems i have to enter :

```
[web]
   push_ssl=False
   allow_push=*
```

into the hgrc file. I have looked in the repo directory under /.hg but there is no hgrc file in this folder i only have, branchheads.cache, dirstate, 00changelog.i, requires, tags,cace, undo.branch, undo.dirstate,

any help would be great so i can push the changes back to the server for other developers to pull down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create `.hgrc` file (note leading dot), if it doesn't exist

Comment: @rugbylad_28 - none. And, BTW, under Tux leading dot means "hidden-file" (and work accordinly)